# Ping/Traceroute ERLANG implementation

Tags: erlang, ping, traceroute

Is there any Erlang implementation of ICMP or UDP ping and traceroute function available? Or may be you can say or show how it could be implemented?

Spent all night googling it - no luck.

Comment: Unless you are doing this purely as an exercise, you are probably barking up the wrong tree. Too often, novice network programmers turn to ping as a way to improve the reliability of their program. If you are using UDP, far better to switch to TCP to improve reliability. If you are using TCP, you'll likely be better served by adding TCP keepalives than throwing ping packets around programmatically. Ping is a network troubleshooting tool, not something programmers should be integrating into their programs.

Comment: It's not the matter of reliability it's the matter of purpose of the program. I need to implement some sort of monitoring service which has to get orders what to check and check  remote hosts by several ways including ping, traceroute etc.